# Incrementing Number of Auctions on Button Click

Tags: php, laravel

The idea is that I have a page where users can make offers for an Auction. Here is that view.

**auction.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-aukcija table-clear">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Auction No</td>
        <td>{{ $auction->id }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Time:</td>
        <td class="counter_polje">
            <strong id="clockdiv"></strong>
            <br>
            <small><em>( {{ date($auction->end_date) }} )</em></small>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of Offers:
            <!-- Here num of offers shall be displayed -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>My offer:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="table-nudjenje-biding">
            <form id="formMojaPonuda" name="formMojaPonuda" action="{{ asset('/auctions/'.$auction->id) }}" method="GET"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="minBid" value="{{ $auction->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" id="minBid" value="{{ $auction->name }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="descript" id="minBid" value="{{ $auction->descript }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" id="minBid" value="{{ $auction->price }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="end_date" id="minBid" value="{{ $auction->end_date }}">
                    <input name="txtIznos" id="bidValue" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="(min. RSD 1.50)"
                           class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name='offerButton'>Make your offer</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/auctions/{id}', 'AuctionController@show');
```

**AuctionController.php**

```
class AuctionController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $auction = new Auction();
        $auction->id = $id;
        $this->data['auction'] = $auction->get();
        return view('pages.auction', $this->data);
    }
}
```

**Auction.php (Model)**

```
class Auction
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $descript;
    public $price;
    public $pic;
    public $end_date;
    public $numOfOffers;

    public function getAll()
    {
        return DB::table('auctions')->select('*')->get();
    }

    public function get()
    {
        return DB::table(a 'auctions')->select('*')->where('id', '=', $this->id);
    }
}
```

So when user makes an offer and clicks offerButton ('Make your offer'), the number of offers for that auction shall increment in the database. For every auction there can be a number of offers, that number shall be displayed for that auction in the corresponding field. However, I don't understand how should I implement that? I tried routing the button to the same route ( `Route::get('/auctions/{id}', 'AuctionController@show');` ) but it failed. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you going to post a form for the offer? Or use AJAX to post? You can't use your get route for this, you need a new route.

Comment: It would be good to use a route, I would not dwell into AJAX just for this small part of the project...

Comment: So basically I just came to the idea, offer button should point to a post route, which should point to a controller, in a controller I can increase a num of offers, and than return auction view (since user should always be returned to the auctions view). I dunno how I did not came with this earlier...

Comment: You could've done this also with AJAX so you don't have to refresh the page every time the user clicks the button.

Comment: "(since user should always be returned to the auctions view)" ; in this case AJAX is the best option.

Comment: But I don't know AJAX at all, and know Laravel little more. And I need to do this in certain time so I would rather go with php even if its more complicated.

Comment: It was quite easy to do, I don't know why you guys wouldn't have wanted to help me. All I did was make a button inside a form, pointed form to a new route, and route went to controller which than redirected to the previous route. Quite simple.